# wrong value in referenced static variable

Tags: pointers, memory, rust, static, webassembly

I'm trying to update a static variable in rust from a WebAssembly module, which itself is written in rust.

To set the variable, I've written a function `init` and exported it to the WASM module:

```rust
static mut FILE_NAME: &str = "";

#[no_mangle]
pub fn init(model_path: *mut c_char) {
    let path = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(model_path).to_str().unwrap() };
    unsafe {
        FILE_NAME = path;
        println!("{}", FILE_NAME);
    }
}
```

Then I try to access it from another exported function `load_model`:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub fn load_model() -> *mut c_char {
    let path = unsafe { &FILE_NAME };
    println!("{}", path);
    // stuff ...
}
```

When invoking the `init` function with a pointer to `"/lib/python/iris_knn.model"` as parameter and then the `load_model` function, I get the following lines printed:

```
lib/python/iris_knn.model
?4?on/iknn.mode
```

which of course is not what I was expecting. What's the problem here?

As a side note, I know this is bad practice but I see it more as a learning.

Comment: Where is the `"/lib/python/iris_knn.model"` string stored? It must be alive when you call `load_model` for this to be sound.

Comment: This was exactly the correct hint. I was instantly deallocating the memory associated with the string after invoking `init`, thus it was not valid anymore at the time of `load_model`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Cerberus comment, I found my own error. I was instantly deallocating memory associated with the passed string, after invoking `init`. The memory is free'd and not valid anymore when accessed from `load_model`.

Here is an excerpt of the correct host runtime code:

```py
# ...
instance = Instance(module, import_object)
(file_ptr, file_len) = get_string_ptr('/lib/python/iris_knn.model', instance)
instance.exports.init(file_ptr)
# the next line is wrong and to be removed
# instance.exports.deallocate(file_ptr, file_len)

def load_model():
    output_ptr = instance.exports.load_model()
    (output, output_len) = get_string_from_ptr(output_ptr, instance)
    instance.exports.deallocate(output_ptr, output_len)
    return output
```